# Do I want to clone a branch of origin master directly into eclipse?

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to Git and am trying to setup a project in Eclipse through the git plugin. From my understanding I don't want to clone the origin master directly because others will be working on that repo as well, but I should create a branch of origin master, and clone that, is that true? If so what will happen to my local repo after I merge my branch back into origin master? Will that become origin master? Or every time I finish a branch, do I have to once again go through the process of making a new branch and cloning it to a new location on my local drive to use as my local repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem unfamiliar with git as a whole, I would highly recommend reading some git guides/tutorials ([here's one](https://www.atlassian.com/git) I used when first starting out) that familiarize you with git concepts. I'll try and explain a bit here as well.

A git repository is simply a collection of files and directories. The repository is stored as the **remote**, which means it's in some central location accessible by everyone who you want to have access (eg. GitHub).

When you *clone* a **remote** repository to your computer, you're creating a **local copy**. Changes in this local copy are *not* reflected in the remote till you *push* those changes to the remote.

I'll also lay out a very basic git workflow/order of operations here:

1. You **checkout** a copy of the remote repository to your local machine.
2. You make some changes to the files.
3. You **add** the files to the index (set of changes you've made) using `git add`.
4. You **commit** the changes to the local repository (save the changes as a new state) using `git commit`.
5. You **push** the changes to the remote repository (overwrite the remote repository with your local changes) using `git push`.

By default, when you clone a git repository to your machine, it checks out the primary (or *master*) branch. Again, any changes you make on your *local copy* of the branch are not reflected in the *remote* branch till you push the changes. Therefore, you can have several people clone the repository to their local machines, make whatever (wildly different) changes they want, and **commit** them (i.e. saving the changes as state locally). None of those changes will be reflected in the remote till they're pushed.

Now, a **branch** is simply a pointer to a **commit** you've made on the repository. Branches allow you to develop in parallel - commits made on one branch are exclusive to that branch until they are **merged** (copied) to another branch.

Now to answer your specific questions:

Q: *I don't want to clone the origin master directly because others will be working on that repo as well, but I should create a branch of origin master, and clone that, is that true?*

A: **Not true.** You *can* clone the master branch directly and make whatever changes you want, since those changes don't affect the remote repository. However, if you're working on a feature, it is a good idea to make those changes on a new feature branch. Once you're done developing, *pull* the latest changes to the master branch from the remote repo (in case someone else has pushed changes to it), *merge* the feature branch into the master branch to copy your changes over, and *push* the changes in the master branch to the remote repo.

Q: *If so what will happen to my local repo after I merge my branch back into origin master?*

A: **Nothing.** After you push your local changes to the remote, your local copy remains as-is and unchanged. You can continue working as normal.

Q: *Will that become origin master?*

A: **Depends.** If you push the changes on your local master branch, you're updating the remote master branch with those changes. If you push the changes on your local feature branch, you're updating the remote feature branch with your changes, and the remote master branch (and all branches other than your feature branch) remain unchanged.

Q: *Or every time I finish a branch, do I have to once again go through the process of making a new branch and cloning it to a new location on my local drive to use as my local repo?*

A: **Not quite.** You only ever have to clone one copy of the repo - that's where git is really useful. You can switch between branches using `git checkout` and make whatever changes you want on any number of different branches. Again, those changes are only local and you need to push them to the remote to see them reflected in the remote repo.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that helps out. We are in the middle of switching from SVN to Git which is causing some confusion, as git does seem to have a few more steps to committing changes.